# What is pointer swizzling?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I was reading about integer overflow on wikipedia , and came across the term **Pointer Swizzling** in the see also collumn.
I googled about pointer swizzling , but couldn't understand it.
Can anyone please explain what is pointer swizzling?

Comment: I think the linked list example on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_swizzling) is excellent. You don't want to persist current memory locations, but their relative positions (serialization/saving = unswizzling, deserialization/loading = swizzling)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The wikipedia page explains this, but let me say it another way.

Say you have a binary tree data structure in memory and want to save the structure to disk.
You can not simply write the structure to disk because the pointers will be invalid on disk.
Also when you later want to read the binary tree from disk back into memory, the addresses
used in the original memory copy of the tree might already be in use in the new process.

Pointer swizzling is converting pointers to handles when writing from memory to disk,
and also converting handles to (different) pointers when reading the disk data back into memory.