# Reading from file to linked list

Tags: c, file, linked-list

Ok, so there's my problem I have 2 structures, the client and item. Basicaly item is nested list inside client. I cant figure out how can I read from file all items and link them to client while reading. I know how it could be done if only I had client structure and had to read from file only clients but its pretty complicated at least for me to do it while I have inner list. How can I separate items from clients in file so that while I read them and relink program will know what input is? I dont want to do it counting how many items are linked to each client and how many clients there are before saving. Here are my structures and save functions.

```
struct item
{
    char item_name[30];
    char item_state[30];
    float item_price;
    char item_status[30];
    float item_price_if_not;
    struct item *next;
};
struct client
{
    char client_name[30];
    char client_last_name[30];
    struct item *item_data;
    struct client *next;
};
void savetxt(struct client *head)
{
    FILE *f;
 f = fopen("data.txt","w");
   if(f == NULL)
   {
       printf("error");
   }
    struct item *CurrentItem = head->item_data;
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(f,"%s %s\n",head->client_name,head->client_last_name);
        while(CurrentItem != NULL)
        {

            fprintf(f,"%s %s %f %s %f ",CurrentItem->item_name,CurrentItem->item_state,CurrentItem->item_price,CurrentItem->item_status,CurrentItem->item_price_if_not);
            CurrentItem = CurrentItem->next;
        }
        head = head->next;
        if(head != NULL)
{
          CurrentItem = head->item_data;
}
        fprintf(f,"\n\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are  many approaches.  Consider using `'('` and `')'`.

You need some delimiter or keyword to set off the data.  By encapsulating each structure with delimiters, reading can determine when a new level of structure is started or completed.

```
int foo(void) {
  ...
  fputc('(', f);
  while (head != NULL) {
    fputc('(', f);
    fprintf(f, "%s %s\n", head->client_name, head->client_last_name);
    while (CurrentItem != NULL) {
      fputc('(', f);
      fprintf(f, "%s %s %f %s %f ", CurrentItem->item_name,
          CurrentItem->item_state, CurrentItem->item_price,
          CurrentItem->item_status, CurrentItem->item_price_if_not);
      CurrentItem = CurrentItem->next;
      fputc(')', f);
    }
    head = head->next;
    if (head != NULL) {
      CurrentItem = head->item_data;
    }
    fputc(')', f);
    fprintf(f, "\n\n");
  }
  fputc(')', f);
}
```

Comment: But how would I recognize that in file there's limitation mark such as ")"? Is there any function to do so while reading file?

Comment: Could you explain how exactly can I do so?

Comment: The file consists of _data_ and _delimiters_.  You all ready have limitations should you want `client_last_name` to contains a space, for you likely use space as a delimiter and not part of data.  The typical solution is to "not allow a space in a last name", that is not robust but may enough for a student program.  Similarly, disallow '(' and ')' from strings.  Then use `scanf()`, with `"%[^() ]"` to read a string that contains no white space nor '(' nor ')'.  The alternative solution is escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is pointers swizzling and unswizzling or serialization deserialization. from wikipedia:

> pointer swizzling is the conversion of references based on name or
>   position to direct pointer references. It is typically performed
>   during the deserialization (loading) of a relocatable object from
>   disk, such as an executable file or pointer-based data structure. The
>   reverse operation, replacing pointers with position-independent
>   symbols or positions, is sometimes referred to as unswizzling, and is
>   performed during serialization (saving)

Basically you will need to add a unique id to each of your structs, and access your struct instances with the id while storing to disk, and reading from.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218432/2549281) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_swizzling)

Comment: Seems way overcomplicated for me as I'm pretty new to programming :x

Comment: @user3209183 it just sounds complicated because of those names swizzling, unswizling. THe idea is simple, ad an id and refer to your struct by id.